# How do i save a date range on just the months, not year or day ie. January through may

Tags: mysql

How do I save a date range on just the months, not year or day, for example January through May?

I am to prepare a table of crops and the appropriate time for planting.  It needs to be non-specific as to year and day.

Some beans can be planted "January through March" or "August through November".

I need to be able to call up a form and select the month of my search and return a list of what crops are appropriate for the month selected.

Should I create a table with fields crop month
and save data as Beans Jan - March
then another entry as Beans August - November

Or

Beans 1,3 and 8,11?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate table to keep track of allowed months for your crops:

```
create table cropmonths
(
  cropid int not null,
  allowedmonth int not null
);
```

So you will have 7 records in that table (one for for each month) that would reference a single "beans" row in crops table.